# AWS Glue - Unable to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-glue

Hi in this instance database security group is open for all inbound traffic (ALL ports - All sources).

I am also able to connect to the database fine in mysql workbench or Datagrip which for sure use jdbc connection string.

```
2019-05-21 14:12:03 INFO CatalogClient:651 - Got connection 'tem-sas-main' info from Catalog with url: jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central
2019-05-21 14:12:03 INFO CatalogClient:684 - JDBC configuration for connection tem-sas-main: JDBCConfiguration(url=jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central, hostname=my-database-example, port=3306, databaseVendor=mysql, databaseVersion=null, connectionName=tem-sas-main, path=sas_tem_central, subnetId=subnet-0717c4db096e84393, availabilityZone=eu-west-1a, securityGroups=[sg-074b074ebc51c2315], enforceSSL=false)
2019-05-21 14:12:03 INFO JdbcConnection:42 - Starting connecter. driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@7e5d9a50
2019-05-21 14:12:03 INFO JdbcConnection:60 - Attempting to connect with SSL host matching: jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central
2019-05-21 14:14:15 INFO JdbcConnection:69 - SSL connection to data store using host matching failed. Retrying without host matching.
2019-05-21 14:14:15 INFO JdbcConnection:83 - Attempting to connect with SSL: jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central
2019-05-21 14:16:26 INFO JdbcConnection:88 - SSL connection to data store failed. Retrying without SSL.
2019-05-21 14:16:26 INFO JdbcConnection:102 - Attempting to connect without SSL: jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central
Check that your connection definition references your JDBC database with correct URL syntax, username, and password. Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Also note my JDBC connection string is

`jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central`

And Require SSL connection is set to false

Comment: Is your MySQL instance secured via SSL? If so, then you need to use a certificate from an accepted Public Certificate Authority: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/configure-access.html#ca-certificates

Comment: How are you trying to connect in glue. Please provide some code snippet.

Comment: @HarshBafna i am trying to connect via JDBC connection and my connection string is "jdbc:mysql://my-database-example:3306/sas_tem_central" - Also Require SSL connection is false

Comment: @JerodJohnson i am using amazon RDS for mysql database i think it has the SSL certificate. Also note i am connecting via JDBC connection and i have set Require SSL connection to false

Comment: I am assuming you gave some spark code for connecting to MySQL in glue etl. Can you share the sample of what you are doing.

Comment: @HarshBafna no its not like that - under the glue service we have connection tab which visually (UI) let you add a new connection and test it. The log i have posted is from Cloudwatch

Comment: @HarshBafna you can read more about this here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-add-connection.html

Comment: @FaizRasool : Are you configuring the same VPC/Security group in glue connection as the the one attached to RDS instance.

Comment: @HarshBafna no they are in different VPC - lets assume they are in different region for simplicity

Comment: Then you will need to configure both the security groups in each other's inbound and outbound rules.

Comment: @HarshBafna both security groups are open to the world on all ports.

Comment: You still need to make separate entry for the security group ID with which you are communicating.

Comment: @HarshBafna will even the security group from different VPC will work?

Comment: @FaizRasool : Yes it is possible. Check out the documentation : https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/

Comment: @FaizRasool : Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: I've received information from the AWS Support that Glue does not support MySQL 8 yet and only 5.x is supported. Additionally I was told that info about MySQL 8.x support should be published at https://aws.amazon.com/new

Answer (score 10):

After speaking to an AWS Architect, I can confirm that Glue does not work with MySql Version 8 at this time.  This is NOT documented anywhere I could find.

Comment: then you can set this as an answer to your question

Comment: You can use your own JDBC driver and a little configuration to make it work with e.g. MySQL 8, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64178019/878612 Granted this isn't out of the box, it requires a little configuration.

Answer (score 8):

[Glue's supported Databases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc) (not pointed out prominently in the Glue documentation / faqs)

The following table lists the JDBC driver versions that AWS Glue supports.

```
Microsoft SQL Server    6.x
MySQL   5.1
Oracle Database 11.2
PostgreSQL  42.x
Amazon Redshift 4.1
```

Now you can [customize your own configuration](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-glue-now-enables-you-to-bring-your-own-jdbc-drivers-to-your-glue-spark-etl-jobs/) to connect to MySQL 8 and other newer databases from AWS Glue Jobs.

1. Download the JDBC driver for MySQL 8
2. Upload to S3
3. Create a JDBC connection to your database via Glue - Tables - Connections
   (Note this will not work using the "test connection" since the latest version supported is (currently) 5.7
4. Edit the Glue Job - Dependent jars path - e.g.
   `s3://yourS3bucket/path/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar`
5. Modify the Glue Job e.g. Python script

```
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf
(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = “GLUE-CONNECTION-NAME”, 
connection_options = { 
"customJdbcDriverS3Path": "s3://yourS3Bucket/path/mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar", 
"customJdbcDriverClassName": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", 
"user": “#DBuserName#”, "password": “DbUsersPassword”, 
"url":"jdbc:mysql://dbname.url.region.rds.amazonaws.com/schemaName, 
"connectionType": "mysql", "dbtable": “tablenameInDb”, 
"database": “schemaName”}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
```

(no new lines in that script)

Answer (score 4):

Your connection string looks right.

I was struggling with this same issue and found that I had to troubleshoot a few issues:

1. Ensure that your security group that you are using for your RDS is self-referenced. This means that you should add the security group from your db instance on RDS to both the inbound and outbound rules for All TCP.
2. Ensure that you have created an endpoint for your VPC. To do this, navigate to your VPC, click on 'Endpoint', add an 'Endpoint' for the VPC that the RDS is in and create an endpoint for S3.
3. Finally, the version you create your MySQL RDS instance on should be version 5 (not version 8). I noticed that AWS Glue JDBC connector only worked with MySQL version 5 (5.7)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the AWS RDS with the MySQL Engine, you don't need to create a JDBC connection. You can use the Amazon RDS when you are creating your connection.

[New Connection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk2RE.png)

Comment: Even if you choose Amazon RDS it will still generate the jdbc string as the connection URI.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried with mysql8. It didn't work. It thrown same error.
Later i created mysql5.7 for testing connection. It worked now. I can able to connect Mysql5.7 from Glue. Makesure your VPC-s3 Endpoint are configured properly.

Thanks
Raaz